# angular2: set method of @Input binding property in custom directive

Tags: angular, set, directive

I am migrating to Angular2 from Angular1 right now. During my app,I came across one confusing point in the custom directive part. The demo code is as following:

```
import { Directive, Input, TemplateRef, ViewContainerRef } from '@angular/core'

@Directive({
     selector: '[myUnless]'
})
export class UnlessDirective {
    @Input('myUnless')
    set condition(newCondition:boolean) {
        if {!newCondition} {
            this.viewContainer.createEmbeddedView(this.templateRef);
        } else {
            this.viewContainer.clear();
        }
    }

    constructor(
        private templateRef: TemplateRef <any>,
        private viewContainer: ViewContainerRef
    ) {}
}

<p *myUnless="boolValue"></p>
```

This is a Structural Directives, the opposite way of NgIf.

The point I can't understand is the `@Input` binding part. Generally speaking, the format is following:

`@Input('myUnless')` 
`condition`

so the `condition` is variable. It's understandable. 
In the above case, based on my search, the `set` is condition's method. Not fully understand. How so?

Comment: That's binding to a property, set is the accessor. See https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/classes.html

Comment: so, this is a typescript syntax and usage. I will check your doc

Comment: @jonrsharpe is correct, you can have a set/get accessor for each property. Pretty useful when you want to perform specific actions when a new value is being set to it.